# Ruby - How to check if a file exists in google cloud storage (Buckets)?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-storage

I was looking for a way to check if a file exists in my bucket using the google-cloud-storage ruby api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2019, a pretty simple way to check it is the following. I suppose the variable `bucket` is a Bucket object from the google cloud storage ruby gem.

```rb
file = bucket.file "i/love/pancakes.png" # Return nil when you ask for an inexisting path
file&.exists? # Return true if the file does exists
```

I agree it looks a bit weird, but it does its job. For a lack of a better answer.

---

For completeness, here is how you retrieve your bucket:

```rb
storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new project_id: "your-project-name"
bucket = storage.bucket "your-bucket-name"
```